# Load existing .XSLT to a GUI, make changes, save new .XSLT?

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, formatting, xsl-fo

I am a Business Analyst and we have a bespoke middleware solution that takes .XML files and uses an .XSLT template to generate a .PDF. This is a background process that occurs hundreds of times a day.

We have no idea who wrote the .XSLT templates, or how (it is a legacy solution), but they run up to several thousand lines of XSL:FO code and we have no in-house resource to write .XSL:FO.

The source .XML file and schema have been expanded to accommodate some additional data. The business want to see this data on the .PDF.

Is there any way i can take the existing .XSLT and the new XML schema, load it into a GUI editor, map in the new fields, make sure it looks "pretty" then generate the "new" .XSLT? I am trying to avoid needing to get the whole template re-coded from scratch for the sake of the one or two tickboxes the business want adding to the .PDF.

I have looked at Altova Style Vision would this do this for me? Any other tools out there?

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Update: Had a reply from RenderX, Stylus Studio and someone on the Altova forum - general consensus is the use case i describe can't be accomodated. I'm stuck with a trial and error of using an editor to modify the XSLT, crank it through Apache FOP and see what damage i have wrought on the .PDF....and start again! :) .... outsourcing it has also been suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options outside of a full rewrite:

1. Edit the XSLT to create the xsl-fo directives necessary for the new data in the input. After all, the only thing the XSLT does is create an FO document that is then fed as input to a processor for generating the PDF (such as Apache FOP).
2. Find some tool that lets you read in the XSLT and presents you with a good way of editing it.

The first might be the easiest. The second could also work, but how well may depend quite a bit on the XSLT...

Altova StyleVision does have a way of importing an XSLT into a project. The templates in the stylesheet then become global templates available for that project. The issue I could foresee here is that plenty of people haven't quite understood the declarative nature of XSLT. Instead of writing nicely modular templates for small pieces of functionality, they make one huge template wherein everything is done procedurally using things like `<xsl:for-each>`. Especially if the existing XSLT was already output by a (legacy) tool it might be quite a mess.

Although I haven't worked with Altova StyleVision, I've worked extensively with XMLSpy and MapForce and can vouch for the quality of the Altova products. I'm in no way affiliated with them, fyi.

Another option is Stylus Studio. I haven't used it, so I'm not sure how good it is. It does seem to be a primary competitor for Altova, though.

Since both products have trial versions (I know the one for Altova lets you work for 30 days and isn't feature-restricted) it's probably best to simply give it a try. If neither works well enough with the legacy XSLT, editing it yourself is your best bet. XMLSpy is very convenient for it since it has XSLT debugging.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, I believe our solution does feed the XSLFO into Apache Fop and this is what generates our .PDF EDIT: Hit return too soon! - our worry with option 1) "the manual route" is we try and decipher what lines of XSLFO we need to insert into the thousands of lines of already existing code and sit for hours going through trial and error until the one tickbox we are trying to add ends up in the right position, then do it again for the next tick box...etc.... I have a good Dev in my team but he's never seen an XLST in his life before! Hence I was looking for option 2.

Comment: PS:  I did come across Stylus Studio this afternoon, along with RenderX and Oxygen - have e-mailed them all with my scenario - will let this thread know if any are suitable but would still appreciate this community's view on my problems :)

Comment: @JungleJme The Altova support forums might be useful as well. You could ask users if the use-case you have would be easy to handle using StyleVision. You might have to provide some more details about the XSLT.

Comment: i have done exactly that, and will keep an eye out for any replies!